# Optimizing webcam picture rate python/cv2

Tags: python, opencv, optimization, computer-vision, webcam

I got a BRIO 4k Logitech Webcam for a research project deducing car velocity through pictures taken of traffic. It is working fine, I am currently trying to optimize the speed of taking pics with the highest possible resolution. I am using Logitech software to disable autofocus & set it to as far as possible (focus not changeable through cv2 as far as I know).

I put my current 3 program files here:

> https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvdFsPpMX-gYrA9zo-r_W340B7b8

`take_photos.py` is the script you need to run, just put all three in a folder and create a subfolder "pics" and it should work. 
func_cam.py includes functions that the main program is calling, params_cam.py some parameters like resolution (set to max throuch the 5k/5k input).

The output will be the time taken to yield each image. Here are some typical outputs I get:

```
1.657
1.587
1.033
0.927
0.719
0.573
0.689
0.508
1.097
1.516
1.409
1.767
```

So you see quite a difference (no change in position, light condition, no moving objects in the imaging area) in times.

1. How can I imporve image speeds, it is still to slow for my purposes (without reducing resolution)
2. The second challenge I am currently facing is the big differences of image rates within a run despite almost no changes in image area or setup. Maybe there is an idea on how to stabilize this (time differences above)?

I am looking forward to your help with these challenges I am facing! Thanks for this and all the best!

Comment: You need more details. What's the CPU usage while this is running? Which part of `take_pics` takes the most time (is the bottleneck)? `cam.read`, `cv2.imwrite` or the `time.sleep`? | Acquisition ought to run in a separate thread from processing/output if you want to maximize throughput and keep a consistent frame rate.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. CPU usage is going from 20% to ~50% once the program is started to go down to 30%-40% after a few seconds. The limiting factor concerning time seems to be the saving: Uncommenting "cv2.imwrite(file, camera_capture)" in func_cam.py yields quite continuous 0.3 seconds for the rest of the process. Can you tell me the best way to speed this up then? Is multithreading an option, if yea in what way? Where can I learn how to do this? Thanks!